# ReactSelect - Allow for Case Sensitive Creatable Options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using React-Select, in my ReactJS Application. I have created a Creatable Select Type, which allows users to Create options on the fly. But I have a problem.

THE PROBLEM:
My options are used in a case-sensitive manner. Whihc means, `user` and `USER` have different applications.

Currently when I type for example `user`, I cannot type `USER` as well.

I am going through the documentation, but cannot find anything that allows me, to use both the Dropdown Select, along with creating multiple `CaseSensitive` options.

Here is my Select:

```
                    <CustomSelect
                      id={id}
                      type={Type.CREATABLE_SELECT}
                      options={convertRegexDataToSelect(value)}
                      onChangeCallback={values => {
                        setFieldValue(name, convertSelectToRegexData(values));
                        setFieldTouched(name, true);
                      }}
                    />
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this functionality?

A working example in a CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-brown-zk7e1

Comment: I [almost] get the problem, but not totally, can you provide a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s) minimal example?

Comment: Yeah, I could do that. A faster route is typing in the MultiSelect example here: `https://react-select.com/creatable`. I will create a Sandbox in the meantime.

Comment: Added a small code sandbox as you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution **UPDATED DUE TO USER FEEDBACK**:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import CreatableSelect from "react-select/creatable";
import { createFilter } from "react-select";
import { colourOptions } from "./colourOptions.js";

export default class CreatableMulti extends Component {
  handleChange = (newValue, actionMeta) => {
    console.group("Value Changed");
    console.log(newValue);
    console.log(`action: ${actionMeta.action}`);
    console.groupEnd();
  };

  handleIsValidNewOption = (inputValue, selectValue, selectOptions) => {
    console.log(inputValue, selectOptions);
    // Check for the same value --> ASD === ASD ?
    const exactValueExists = selectOptions.find(el => el.value === inputValue);
    // Check if the value has a valid length.
    // Without this, it will show create option for empty values.
    const valueIsNotEmpty = inputValue.trim().length;
    // If true show create option.
    return !exactValueExists && valueIsNotEmpty;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <CreatableSelect
        isMulti={true}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={colourOptions}
        filterOption={createFilter({ ignoreCase: false })}
        isValidNewOption={this.handleIsValidNewOption}
      />
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<CreatableMulti />, rootElement);
```

As from: [isValidNewOption Prop](https://react-select.com/props).

Comment: Are you saying that the above, allows you to create both `one` and `ONE` as options?

Comment: This is for filtering the existing options, that's what I thought your are looking for, I didn't check that against creating new options, I'll do ASAP.

Comment: @DimitrisEfst , The old answer provided a solution for filtering values in a case-sensetive manner, I made an update so that you can create options the same as filtering them. `ASD` `asd` `AsD` `aSd` can be created as different values now. Please check the updated.